# Transferring Intellij Live Templates Between Machines

Tags: intellij-idea, live-templates

I'm trying to figure out how to transfer the templates in the /.IdeaC10/config/templates/user.xml file to my coworker's machines.

If I copy into the user.xml file, then those changes seem to be getting squashed by Intellij, reverting to the old file contents.

Anyone know how to work around this?

EDIT:

Is there any way to do this by copying and pasting the xml?  That would be preferrable...!

Answer (score 4):

Use [File | Imprort/Export Settings](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/exporting-and-importing-settings.html).

Comment: Is there any way to do this by copying and pasting the xml?  That would be preferrable...!

Comment: Yes, just make sure that IDEA is shut down when you copy the new file.

Comment: I was doing that... it was doing was working.  Just bit the bullet and used import/export.

Answer (score 3):

If you have **Settings Repository** set you may find your **Live Templates** stored in

```
<your_user_home_directory>\
  .IntelliJIdea<version>\
    config\
      settingsRepository\
        repository\
          templates
```

Comment: I was going insane trying to get the other location to work. This worked for me, thanks!

Comment: This is now in C:\Users\{user's home folder}\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea<version>\templates

Answer (score 3):

## An improved and easier way

This allows you to share them easily between collegues.

You can select multiple live templates and then copy them (right click and select copy, or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>). This gives you XML-descriptions in your clipboard you can send to others.

Other can then take that XML, and paste it into a "Template Group". Right click one of the groups and select `Paste`. If the option is greyed out, you didn't select a *group* but something else.

Answer (score 1):

the technique of copying and pasting the xml file on another computer in the correct directory, function perfectly for me! But the name of my template file is android.xml for my Android developments. Maybe the file name "user" is protected. Try maybe with a different file name

Comment: The *correct directory* is `~/.IntelliJIdea14/config/templates/`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the required custom template groups and update the relevant predefined groups as necessary and click OK. Based on these changes, IntelliJ IDEA generates the `<group_name>.xml` files, see Location of Custom Live Templates Definitions above.

Depending on the operating system you are using, the .xml files are stored at the following locations:

```
Windows: <your_user_home_directory>.IntelliJ IDEA<version_number>\config\templates
Linux: ~IntelliJ IDEA<version>\config\templates
OS X: ~/Library/Preferences/IntelliJ IDEA<version>/templates
```

Refer to [Intellij Help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/sharing-live-templates.html) article.

Comment: Does not seem to apply to EPA. There is no "templates" in my %HOMEPATH%\.IntelliJIdea2017.2\config /sadface