# Export/Share Intellij Idea Project Template

Tags: intellij-idea

I´m using the Community Edition of Intellij Idea. There I was able to save a project as a template and use this template locally. However I´m stuck while trying to export/share it, since the only action available in *Tools/Manage Project Templates* is to remove an already created template.

Answer (score 2):

for idea 2016.2 ( i don't know if in earlier version those are available - you need to check it)

use either for idea 2016.2 (I don't know if in earlier version those are available - you need to check it):

> - File -> **Import/Export Settings.**...

or available for all IntelliJ Platform based products (build number greater than 139.69/140.2):

> - File -> **Settings Repository**... (to setup settings repo)
> - VCS -> Sync settings -> ...  (to sync later)

for details see: https://github.com/develar/settings-repository

Answer (score 1):

Although it doesn´t have the exact answer, I was able to find a way to do this after reading this [SO-Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7516011/transferring-intellij-live-templates-between-machines)

In ***USER*\.IdeaICXXX\config\projectTemplates** are my project templates in zip format. These can be just copied to another computer and placed in the same relative path and everything works smoothly.